# Page Jumping Error from HTML to PHP - Site coded in tables?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a site that was previously developed by someone else.

You can see the site here: http://www.pivotalevents.com/nonametag/index.html

Having issue on this page here: http://www.pivotalevents.com/nonametag/introduce.php

I have coded in a CAPTCHA on the contact page and used some PHP, making the page a PHP extension file 'introduce.php'. Previously it was 'introduce.html'.

**The problem:** When going from any page on the site, to the contact page, the entire contact page jumps around. The page expands, then collapses back to it's normal width. If you look at the logo, you can see it jump out, then back in.

When I change the page back to .html extension, it doesn't do this.

Why is this happening? Is it because the site's main wrapper is a table?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrapped the site in div tags and now the page does not jump. Seems there was a problem related to the tables and switching from HTML to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this could be because the site's main wrapper is in a table...

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just wanted to see if I was missing something... The problems of dealing with older code, lol!

Comment: The question I really have is, why does it do this with the PHP file and not the HTML?